# Case when after select not producing value

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, case

Table

```
Type   |  Name   |   Condition
Fruit  |  Apple  |    Fair
Fruit  |  Apple  |    Fair
Veg    |   null  |    Good
Veg    |  Tomato |    Great
```

Query

```
SELECT 
    a.Type,
        CASE
        WHEN (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM Table
        WHERE a.fruit=fruit
        AND a.name=name
        AND a.condition=condition) > 1 THEN 'Duplicate'
    WHEN a.Name ='' THEN 'Blank'
    ELSE a.Name
    END as Name,
FROM Table a;
```

Trying to get the case to show values for duplicates and blanks.  The second WHEN statement that I want to produce as "Blank" does not produce a value after running the statement.  This seems to only happen after running a SELECT sub query.

Comment: The query is referencing columns **`fruit`** and **`color`** which are not shown as columns in the table (unfortunately) named **`table`**. But thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*?

Comment: @spencer7593 sorry updated it.  My problem is  **WHEN a.name = '' THEN 'Blank'** does not produce anything.  I'd like it to show which columns are blank after running.

Comment: Maybe `a.name` is not equal to an empty string... maybe it's a NULL value, or a single space, or some other whitespace characters. In the example rows shown for the table, we don't see any row where `name` appears to be equal to an empty string. (I'd like a pony and free pizza.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I used null as empty (maybe I should've left it blank).  The same code works for another column, but it doesn't for the other three which is the strange part.

Comment: If you want to check for NULL values, then test for a NULL value... **`WHEN a.Name IS NULL THEN 'Blank'`**.

Comment: @spencer7593 my mistake, after a closer look the issue only seems to happen on the last column where there is a return in the field.  Is there a character that is the equivalent to a return in MySQL? \n maybe?